# What should our chat room's name be?

Tags: discussion, chat

"Space Exploration" is the default name for our [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9682/space-exploration), but that's a little on the bland side. What would be a fitting name for the default SpaceEx room?

Answer (score 10):

**The Pod Bay**

Dave went there to chat to Frank...seems appropriate

[image]

Comment: + 1 for grand master historical fiction reference - 1 for using movie image rather then a book quote - 1 for negative space exploration reference = -1 total vote

Comment: @JamesJenkins - A bit too serious approach perhaps? While it's the main contender with my own proposal, it doesn't really matter that much, it's just some fun name we'll be constantly repeating in comments to posts in Q&A: "Please stop by at The Pod Bay", "Would you care to continue this discussion in The Pod Bay, where HAL can't hear us" (not really true, but then again, it wasn't in the movie either LOL),... And meta voting doesn't reflect in user's reputation either, so no need to excuse your personal preference - that's all this voting here is about. ;)

Answer (score 8):

**Captain's Log**

[image: Captain's Log]

Comment: Even more than The Pod Bay, this name reads as being about SF not science.

Comment: @DanNeely - A bit of self-reflective humor never hurts. The main chat room for [security.se] is "The DMZ" for example. Chat rooms are mostly mentioned in the Q&A part either when someone is too chatty in the comments, or they have a question that would solicit debate, would be off-topic, yet regulars still feel they could help out in the chat room. Other contents are either disputes that don't fit here in meta (humor is a must then IMO), or general chatter about life, the Universe, and everything of the regulars. ;)

Comment: The DMZ still says security to me.  The top two suggestions here both appear to reference something else; and while it appears my opinion is the minority I didn't want to just leave drive by down votes.

Answer (score 4):

The Spaceport.

Could be a fun name.

Answer (score 4):

**Houston**

*Hello, Houston, I've got a problem...*

Answer (score 3):

**Space Oddity**

[image]

To celebrate the [first music video shot in space](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KaOC9danxNo). Commander Chris Hadfield performed a revised version of David Bowie's Space Oddity aboard the International Space Station and received a tweet from David Bowie, saying simply: *[Hallo Spaceboy...](https://twitter.com/DavidBowieReal/statuses/333717231236173824)* Related news article in [The Independent](http://www.independent.co.uk/arts-entertainment/music/news/the-real-star-man-david-bowie-champions-canadian-astronaut-chris-hadfields-space-oddity-cover-8613787.html).

Answer (score 2):

**The Holodeck**

[image: What happens in Holodeck...]

Answer (score 1):

Way Out There

Just a thought, something fun:-)

Answer (score 1):

Space Above and Beyond. If you remember the show that is.

Answer (score 1):

**The Hein Line**

Obvious nod to Robert A. Heinlein the most notable Rocket Scientist **and** Science Fiction Author.

While there are many great authors and scientist, no one else combined the two as well as he did.

Answer (score 0):

Ten Forward! Stealing for Star Trek of course.